# Manga with a female lead and a big guy that's considered a savage to nobles

Tags: story-identification, manga

The female lead got pulled from her body because God thought she was dead, and she got reincarnated or isekaied to her favorite novel. It starts off with her becoming an empress and the prince became a stalker and killed her.

This caused her to regress because she wants to have a good ending, so she decides to go to a person she's been writing letters to in her previous life that is considered a savage to nobles, and the guy wasn't what she was thinking of also the letters that the guy had in his previous life appeared in his drawer. It might also be a webcomic.

The guy had scars on his body old scars he I think was a Duke I'm not entirely sure. I remember this gigantic creature with the flower on top of it's head. It was a web comic I saw online probably through one of the many recommendations, the prince that stabbed and killed the female lead in the beginning had yellow hair, the male lead had either brown or black hair.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you remember the names of any characters or locations?

Comment: Welcome to SF&F. Could you change your description to make it a bit clearer? :)

Comment: I do not remember any names of the characters but I do know that the male lead is big as a grizzly and it lives up in the North where it's cold. She's also I believe a purple hair girl

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *[Another Typical Fantasy Romance](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/another-typical-fantasy-romance)*, also identified [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/269383). It is licensed by [Pocket Comics](https://www.pocketcomics.com/comic/3611).

[image: Cover image]

> After **the gods dropped her in the world of her favorite fantasy romance novel**, Lithera was quick to realize that happily-ever-afters were never easy to get. Given another shot at happiness, she is now determined to avoid the mistakes of her previous life, **starting by meeting the sweet and caring Grand Duke she spent years exchanging letters with**… Another typical female lead, with another typical Duke, promised to Wed. Will this story go the typical path we all expect?

Synopsis covers much of it. After getting killed by the prince she married, she goes to meet her penpal that she never saw in her previous life. His appearance is definitely savage-looking.

[image: His appearance]

The letters they had exchanged in her past life do appear in his drawer, and he confirms god's intervention with a priest, which is also why he so readily trusts her when she shows up out of nowhere.

Comment: The "gigantic creature with the flower on top of it's head" I don't recall, but it's otherwise a perfect match.

Comment: Yes this is the one I was talking about!

Comment: Ch 21 is where it appears...